# Can't save blended file? Unable to pack file source path?

Tags: blend-files

This keeps coming up I can't save any files, I put everything in the same folder, I have two different models I made one in cycles the other in blender

I combined both of them into one folder...Blender doesn't seem to work the same as MMD...anyway

One is a 3d character the other is a model of a room

I can't save
[image]

Comment: Do you have *autopack* enabled in *File > External data*?

Comment: Make the paths relative: https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/relative_paths.html